# Android Multiple Spinner with OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

As I stated in the headline, I am having difficult times with multiple spinner onitemselectedlistener method while using them inside a tab fragment.  On my activity, there will more than 1 tab, and I can achieve it with using tab fragments without a problem. In the first tab, I show users what they entered till now, by loading data from db, and in 2nd tab, I am asking them for more information. Problem I have is with 2nd tab at the moment, in which I used 2 different spinners. 1st spinner is for showing users if they entered some data already, and its adapter is filled with data from db. In 2nd one, I just show some integers for users to choose.

I have no problem on loading them to view, I can see both adapters are filled correctly, however there is a problem that I cannot solve yet. Problem is with my onItemSelected listener.

I use a switch statement for doing my stuff on different spinners as follows :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Log.d("logging", "parent id is : " + parent.getId() + " view id is : " + view.getId());
        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.sptChooser:
            Log.d("logging", "load bf from position : " + position);
            loadSPTEntries(position + 1);
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerBorehole:
            sampleDepth = (Double) spinner.getSelectedItem();
            Log.d("logging", " value of clicked item is : " + sampleDepth);
            double value = sampleDepth + .45;
            Log.d("logging", " value of clicked item is after addition : "
                    + value);
            spinnerAdditionText.setText(" - " + value);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

However, for some reason, I cannot see event from my first spinner(sptChooser), while I can see log from (spinnerBorehole). Interesting thing is, in the same view, when I change my tab to first one, and then again swithching back to 2nd tab, I can see that now I can capture itemselects from 1st spinner too.

Any idea about that problem will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it multiple spinners in 2nd Tab?
May be try to add different **OnItemSelectedListener** on different **Spinner**

Comment: Yes @calvinfly , multiple spinners are in 2nd Tab. I tried to use different OnItemSelectedListener, but still same behaviour.

Comment: In different OnItemSelectedListener, using **switch** to distinguish Spinner?

Comment: no, i used different listeners also, without implementing a general way with switch case, but the same behaviour happens. I will try your site and let you know in a minute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: unfortunately, same behaviour is persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the code, I checked my db methods which are AsyncTask. Interesting thing is that, I can see values comes into adapter, but it did not work at all. After calling my db methods beforehand, I managed to work it without a problem.

Seems like one need to check asynctask db methods before anything else..